# How to limit the length of sharepoint multiline field through vb?

Tags: sharepoint-server, vba, multiline-text-field

I want to limit the maximum number of characters in multi-line text field of a sharepoint list programmatically in VB.

I found a field UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary, 
by making this as true it will allow unlimited length. But what exactly happens if I set this to false? To what length it limits?

How can I limit it to 500 characters?

Refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldmultilinetext.unlimitedlengthindocumentlibrary.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It will restrict to the default 255 characters(multi-line field).